# How to get a decimal point from a virtual number pad?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, decimal-point, numpad

I am trying to get the Decimal point to display with the click of an GUI button. I using the method below, which works fine for the numbers but not the decimal point. Any advise would be great. thanks

```
private void displayWeightedquantity(ActionEvent event){
    JButton currentButton = null;
    JButton[] numberButtonsarray = {bnDecimal,bnZero,bnOne, bnTwo, bnThree, bnFour, bnFive,bnSix,bnSeven,
                                    bnEight,bnNine};
        
    currentButton = (JButton)event.getSource();  
    for (int i = 0; i <numberButtonsarray.length; i++){
         if (currentButton == numberButtonsarray[i]){
             lbDisplayitemQty.setText(lbDisplayitemQty.getText() + currentButton.getText());  
             break;
             }
        } 
   }
```

My virtual numberpad :

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - I suspect that `ActionEvent.getActionCommand()` will produce the character that most of that code is designed to determine.

Comment: Why are you looping over the buttons? Instead you could have;

    `if (currentButton != bnPurcahse || currentButton != bnClear)
          lbDisplayitemQty.setText(lbDisplayitemQty.getText() + currentButton.getText());`


This is a much more efficient way of implementing the same functionality.

Anyways, your code looks good to me so I would assume you have some typo type of error with `bnDecimal` causing the `currentButton == numberButtonsarray[i]` to never be met for `.`. I don't see any errors in that logic so I would look elsewhere (or take the above advice :).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I followed your advice even though I hate reading this with the comment formatting.

Comment: I suspect the problem is else where in your code.  The test I set up works find.  You need to provide a functional example the shows the problem, not just a code snippet.  Make sure that the decimal button has it's action listener attached

Comment: @evanmcdonnal  I agree about reading code in comments.  It is horrendous.  OTOH we need to stick to the conventions of SO.  If that means the OP gets code back in a form that is difficult to read, they just need to deal with it.

Comment: @ Andrew and MadProgrammer :- The action listener was missing. I am just a student guys..thank you

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"Make sure that the decimal button has it's action listener attached"*  It seems your intuitive leap is correct.  Care to enter that as an answer?

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's amazing the number of times I've done that exact same thing :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer  ..Do you have a crystal ball?  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, just years of stupid, silly little mistakes ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is else where in your code.

The test I set up works find.

You need to provide a functional example the shows the problem, not just a code snippet.

Also, make sure that the decimal button has it's action listener attached